# Issue with runing PM2-runtime npm start as docker CMD

Tags: docker, npm, devops, pm2

I am trying to run `pm2-runtime npm start` as a docker CMD.
When I go into the container and run `pm2-runtime npm start` everything is ok but I want to automate it.

I have tried:

`CMD ["pm2-runtime", "npm start"]`

`CMD ["pm2-runtime", "npm", "start"]`

`CMD ["pm2-runtime", "'npm start'"]`

The above commands don't work and all-cause this kind of error 
`Usage: npm <command>
where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami`

Seams like an easy issue and pm2-runtime is capable of npm start, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, `npm start` and `pm2-runtime` both run application in the foreground, then any special reason for running `npm start` with pm2-runtime?

As you can wrapped into a [proper Node.js production environment](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/) with process.yml instead of `npm start`.

process.yml

```
apps:
  - script : myapp.js
    name   : 'myapp'
    error_file : './logs/myapp.log'
    out_file : './logs/myapp.log'
```

you can also start multiple process in YML config file.

```
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "process.yml"]
```

Now come to your problem so you can just change your CMD to below and it should work.

```
CMD pm2-runtime 'npm start'
```

or

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "pm2-runtime 'npm start'"]
```

For complete demo app, you can check [nodejs-docker-pm2-runtime](https://github.com/Adiii717/nodejs-docker-pm2-runtime)